# Lenovo S10, webcam not working with Windows Live Messenger

Tags: webcam, lenovo-laptop, windows-live-messenger

I have a Lenovo S10 with a webcam, and i want to use it for video chats with some friends of mine. However Windows Live Messenger seems to think i haven't a webcam installed even when i do. I've checked Devices and Printers and it shows up there, so it's not that the machine doesn't see the camera. I don't have any other software on hand to test the camera at the moment but i could get some if neccessary. OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. How can i get the webcam working with WLM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC on the Lenovo S10 **Fn + ESC** is the key combo to toggle the webcam on/off.

*note: the Fn key may require some 'hotkey' driver from Lenovo.*

Comment: Nope that doesn't work, the camera is on but WLM doesn't see it.

Comment: although the webcam is showing in the device manager, it can still be turned off. do you test the camera (e.g. with MS Paint, file, from scanner or camera, this should get you a still picture from the webcam)?

Comment: I'll test that and check. Though when i use that it removes and adds it from devices and printers.

Comment: Apparently it works nw though i'm not sure how if fixed it. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: this is the time of the year for little miracles :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Same netbook. But I found out it works when the other person invites me.